# When is a function try block useful?

Tags: c++, function, function-try-block

I'm wondering when programmers use function try blocks. When is it useful?

```
void f(int i)
try
{
   if ( i  < 0 ) 
      throw "less than zero";
   std::cout << "greater than zero" << std::endl;
}
catch(const char* e)
{
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
}

int main() {
        f(1);
        f(-1);
        return 0;
}
```

Output: (at [ideone](http://ideone.com/BcBo9))

```
greater than zero
less than zero
```

EDIT: As some people might think that the syntax of function defintion is incorrect (because the syntax doesn't look familiar), I've to say that no its not incorrect. Its called function-try-block. See §8.4/1 [dcl.fct.def] in the C++  Standard.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889811/function-try-blocks-but-not-in-constructors

Comment: I've seen it abused to implement `void f() synchronized { }` in C++.

Comment: @Johannes: Where does this `synchronized` come from? How can anyone abuse it using `synchronized` whatever it means in C++?

Comment: @Nawaz no, they implemented that. It's a macro that makes the function behave like Java's synchronized functions. And they abused function try blocks for this. AFAIR, it was shown off by Alexandrescu :)

Comment: @Nawaz See http://drdobbs.com/184401728, "Finally, Java's synchronized keyword is applicable to entire methods..."

Comment: @Johannes: put this as an answer so that we can upvote it.

Comment: @Johannes: I agree with @Alexandre. Also, you seem to disagree with Alexandrescu?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You use it in constructors to catch errors from initializers. Usually, you don't catch those errors, so this is a quite exceptional use.

Otherwise, it is useless: unless I'm proven wrong,

```
void f() try { ... } catch (...) { ... }
```

is strictly equivalent to

```
void f() { try { ... } catch (...) { ... } }
```

Comment: `ctor-initializer`. Initialization lists are something else.

Comment: ***WARNING***: in constructors and destructors, the exception is ***still rethrown _implicitly_ after catch ends***, so they are still nearly useless - see e.g.: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=496

Comment: @akavel: they are not useless. You may want to perform some cleanup or logging before having the exception rethrown. Or you may want to throw another exception (which is allowed). Actually, the behavior is understandable: if a subobject or a base failed to get constructed, then the object cannot be constructed successfully and has to throw.

Comment: @akavel You're allowed to `return` from the catch-block of a destructor, in which case the exception is not rethrown, as the goal of properly destroying the object is considered accomplished. In the case of a constructor, I agree with Alexandre C.'s comment.

Answer (score 18):

Aside from the functional uses mentioned, you can use the function-try-block to save yourself one level of indentation. *(Ack, an answer about coding styles!)*

Typically you see examples with the function-try-block like so:

```
void f(/*...*/)
try {
   /*...*/
}
catch(/*...*/) {
    /*...*/
}
```

Where the function scope is indented to the same level as if there were no function-try-block.  This can be useful when:

- you have an 80 character column limit and would have to wrap lines given the extra indentation.
- you are trying to retrofit some existing function with try catch and don't want to touch all the lines of the function. (Yeah, we could just use `git blame -w`.)

Though, for functions that are entirely wrapped with a function-try-block, I would suggest **not** alternating between some functions using function-try-blocks and some not within the same code base.  Consistency is probably more important then line wrapping issues.
:)

Answer (score 17):

Function try block are useful for me in two contexts.

a) To have a catch all clause around `main()` allowing to write small utilities without having to worry about local error handling:

```
int main()
try {
    // ...
    return 0;
}
catch (...) {
    // handle errors
    return -1;
}
```

which is clearly just syntactic sugar for having a try/catch inside `main()` itself.

b) to handle exceptions thrown by base class constructors:

```
struct B {
     B() { /*might throw*/ }
};

struct A : B {
     A() 
     try : B() { 
         // ... 
     } 
     catch (...) {
         // handle exceptions thrown from inside A() or by B() 
     } 
};
```

Comment: (a) Sugar is usually sweet. I dispute that that is "sweet". (b) Base class construction failure should usually result in derived class construction failure, and if your uncaught exception does not signify an exceptional case preventing base class construction, then you're abusing exceptions; this is a code smell IMO.

Comment: Tomalek, I believe you're just to quick with your assessment. It's not always possible to handle the exceptions locally in the base class or member constructor, as you might not have control over that source code. And sometimes you can and have to continue executing even if the base class throws (for instance, a database connect or a file open, which may fail), but still finish constructing the derived class, leaving it in a valid state.

Comment: @hkaiser: If your base object throws but you can still have a derived object in "a valid state", I believe that you are using inheritance inappropriately. If the base object is not in a valid state, then the derived object can not be in a valid state. (Note, *objects* not *classes*.)

Comment: Sometimes you don't care what a constructor throws; you just want *any* exception caught and then a *known* exception thrown, because upstream there's a handler that needs to distinguish "my constructor threw for some reason" from "some other code of mine threw", preventing it from using the catch-all.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: That's a good case. (Though inheritance renders it unnecessary)

Comment: How does inheritance have anything to do with it?

Comment: @Tomalak: The `catch` block of the constructor always throws or rethrows. There is an implicit `throw;` added at the end of it. So, even as @hkaiser has written this, it does not imply the object is left valid.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: Because you can achieve the same goal when your exception types follow a proper inheritance tree, by catching a ref-to-base-type.

Comment: @Tomalak: I agree with you: the only valid case I would accept such a construct is when you inherit from a 3rd party class which throws an exception which is not in your tree, and that you want to convert. Every other case (and the same goes for member objects construction errors) smells.

Comment: @AlexandreC: That's my opinion, precisely, yes.

Comment: @Tomalak: Sometimes I have no control over the inheritance pattern of thrown exceptions. For example, I may have a class that contains a member pulled in from some other library; I cannot force that library's exceptions (which may not be well documented) to be in my exception class hierarchy. I still want to catch their exceptions, along with system exceptions like `bad_alloc` and any new exceptions added later without having to rewrite my code. Thus the desire to use a catch-all in my constructor and throw a known exception under my control.

Comment: @Mike: i.e. what Alexandre just said.

Comment: FWIW I used a function-try block last week to "rewrite" an exception thrown by the initialisation of a data member. I didn't even feel that bad about it... :)

Answer (score 11):

Notes regarding how function try blocks operate:

- For constructors, a function try block encompasses the construction of data members and base-classes.
- For destructors, a function try block encompasses the destruction of data members and base-classes.  It gets complicated, but for C++11, you have to include `noexcept(false)` in the declaration of your destructor (or that of a base/member class) or any destruction exception will result in termination at the conclusion of the catch block.  It may be possible to prevent this by putting a `return` statement in the catch block (but this won't work for constructors).
- A catch block in a constructor or destructor must throw some exception [(or it will implicitly rethrow the caught exception)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921250/constructor-as-a-function-try-block-exception-aborts-program).  It is not legal to simply `return` (at least in constructor's function catch block).  Note, however, that you could call `exit()` or similar, which might make sense in some situations.
- A catch block can't return a value, so it doesn't work for functions returning non-void (unless they intentionally terminate the program with `exit()` or similar).  At least that is [what I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11535436/86967).
- The catch block for a constructor-function-try can't reference data/base  members since they will have either have 1) not been constructed or 2) been destructed prior to the catch.  As such, function try blocks are not useful for cleaning up an object's internal state -- the object should already be completely "dead" by the time you get there.  **This fact makes it very dangerous to use function try blocks in constructors, since it is difficult to police this rule over time if your compiler(s) don't happen to flag it.**

valid (legal) uses

- Translating an exception (to a different type/message) thrown during the constructor or it's base/member constructors.
- Translating or absorbing and exception thrown during the destructor or it's base/member destructors ([destructor etiquette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor) notwithstanding).
- Terminating a program (perhaps with a useful message).
- Some kind of exception logging scheme.
- Syntactic sugar for void-returning functions that happen to need a fully encapsulating try/catch block.

Comment: It would seem that while `return` statements aren't allowed in the catch-clause(s) of a constructor's function-try-block, they _are_ allowed in a normal function's; in fact, reaching the end of a catch-clause on a normal function is equivalent to `return;` for functions that return `void`, and undefined otherwise.  This is shown in the final example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block , and code that includes a return statement in the catch-clause compiles on both GCC and Visual Studio.

Comment: It would appear that destructors use a combination of ctor and normal function rules: Reaching the end of a catch-clause normally is equivalent to `throw;`, but return statements are allowed.

Comment: For a program that demonstrates this behaviour on normal functions, see http://ideone.com/YM62JS .

Answer (score 6):

It might be useful if you want to catch exceptions from constructor's initializer.

However, if you do catch exception in constructor that way, you *have* to either rethrow it or throw new exception (i.e. you cannot just normally return from constructor). If you do not rethrow, it just happens implicitly.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
  A()
  try {
    throw 5;
  }
  catch (int) {
    std::cout << "exception thrown\n";
    //return; <- invalid
  }
};

int main()
{
  try {
    A a;
  }
  catch (...) {
    std::cout << "was rethrown";
  }
}
```

Comment: `ctor-initializer`. Initializer lists are something else.

Answer (score 5):

Another thing you can use them for is to provide extra data during debugging, in a manner that doesn't interfere with the finished build.  I haven't seen anyone else use or advocate it, but it's something I find convenient.

```
// Function signature helper.
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
    #define FUNC_SIG __FUNCSIG__
#elif defined(__unix__)
    #define FUNC_SIG __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
// Add other compiler equivalents here.
#endif  /* Function signature helper. */

void foo(/* whatever */)
#ifdef     DEBUG
try
#endif  /* DEBUG */
{
    // ...
}
#ifdef     DEBUG
catch(SomeExceptionOrOther& e) {
    std::cout << "Exception " << e.what() << std::endl
              << "* In function: " << FUNC_SIG << std::endl
              << "* With parameters: " << /* output parameters */ << std::endl
              << "* With internal variables: " << /* output vars */ << std::endl;

    throw;
}
#endif  /* DEBUG */
```

This would allow you to both obtain useful information while testing your code, and easily dummy it out without affecting anything.