# Curly brackets and the returned value in the main method

Tags: c++

I read this [code](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Solutions/Ch4/e4-5.cpp) (by Bjarne Stroustrup). I am confused... The `main` function body is not in the `{}`, and function doesn't return value (as `int`). And it works... Why?

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h" 

int main()
try
{
    cout<< "please enter two floating-point values separated by an operator\n The operator can be + - * or / : ";
    double val1 = 0;
    double val2 = 0;
    char op = 0;
    while (cin>>val1>>op>>val2) {   // read number operation number
        string oper;
        double result;
        switch (op) {
        case '+':
            oper = "sum of ";
            result = val1+val2; 
            break;
        case '-':
            oper = "difference between ";
            result = val1-val2; 
            break;
        case '*':
            oper = "product of ";
            result = val1*val2; 
            break;
        case '/':
            oper = "ratio of";
            if (val2==0) error("trying to divide by zero");
            result = val1/val2; 
            break;
        //case '%':
        //  oper = "remainder of ";
        //  result = val1%val2; 
        //  break;
        default:
                error("bad operator");
        }
        cout << oper << val1 << " and " << val2 << " is " << result << '\n';
        cout << "Try again: ";
    }
}
catch (runtime_error e) {   // this code is to produce error messages; it will be described in Chapter 5
    cout << e.what() << '\n';
    keep_window_open("~");  // For some Windows(tm) setups
}
catch (...) {   // this code is to produce error messages; it will be described in Chapter 5
    cout << "exiting\n";
    keep_window_open("~");  // For some Windows(tm) setups
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That code is using a [Function Try Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612486/when-is-a-function-try-block-useful), which is a special syntax allowing to embed the whole body of a function in a try/catch block (mostly useful for class constructors, in order to catch exceptions thrown by the constructors of base or member sub-objects).

Moreover, `main()` is the only value-returning function which is not required to return a value explicitly. When no return value is specified, `0` is assumed.

Per paragraph 3.6.1/5 of the C++11 Standard:

> A return statement in `main` has the effect of leaving the `main` function (destroying any objects with automatic
>   storage duration) and calling `std::exit` with the return value as the argument. If control reaches the end
>   of `main` without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing
>
> ```
> return 0;
> ```

Comment: Just a question: Does the standard say anything about `0` being assumed, or will this be compiler dependent?

Comment: @Magtheridon96: It is specified by the Standard

Comment: @Magtheridon96: Added the quote to the answer

Comment: why the `keep_window_open("~");` code rows doesn't occur? It was must to show the prompt about the "~" pressing... The `std_lib_facilities.h` here: <http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h >.

Comment: @Bush: That function call is in a `catch` handler. If an exception is not thrown inside the `try` block, control will never be transferred to a `catch` handler and the program will simply terminate without exceptions

Comment: @Andy Prowl: Yes, I know. But I've break the cicle via the invalid data, and the exception must occur.

Comment: @Bush: I can't try it myself since I do not have all the code, but if I were you I would try using a debugger and placing a breakpoint inside the `catch` block to verify whether control gets there. My bet is that it does

Comment: @Andy Prowl: Oh no... I am not right. I was inattentive. Thank you.