# Catching exceptions from a constructor means that my instance is out of scope afterward

Tags: c++, constructor, exception, scope, try-catch

I have a class whose constructor may throw an exception. Here’s some code that will catch the exception:

```
try {
    MyClass instance(3, 4, 5);
}
catch (MyClassException& ex) {
    cerr << "There was an error creating the MyClass." << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

But of course no code after the try/catch can see `instance` because it’s now out of scope. One way to resolve this would be to declare and define `instance` separately:

```
MyClass instance;
try {
    MyClass instance(3, 4, 5);
}
...
```

except that my class doesn’t have the appropriate zero-argument constructor. In fact, this case right here is the only one in which such a constructor would even make sense: the `MyClass` object is intended to be immutable, in the sense that none of its data members change after construction. If I were to add a zero-argument constructor I’d need to introduce some instance variable like `is_initialized_` and then have every method check to make sure that that variable is `true` before proceeding. That seems like far too much verbosity for such a simple pattern.

What is the idiomatic way to deal with this kind of thing? Do I need to suck it up and allow instances of my class to be declared before they’re initialized?

Comment: Put all the code inside a function, call the function in the try block.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If there's an exception, there's no object, so what possible need could you have with `instance`?

Comment: "What is the idiomatic way to deal with this kind of thing?" - don't use `try`/`catch` at all, unless you can handle the failure locally.

Comment: Consider redesigning your class so that the constructor can no longer possibly encounter the error situation which makes him throw the `MyClassException` in the first place.

Comment: What are you going to do with the "failed-to-create" object? If you need to store info why it failed to create, store it in the exception.

Comment: @ChristianHackl With respect, I don't think that's particularly useful advice. Throwing an exception from a constructor is the idiomatic RAII way to do things if there was a a problem creating the object, right? My object is created by deserializing a file; that the file might not be valid is a possibility I can't avoid.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think that may be the way for me to go in this situation.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm coming to C++ from Objective-C, so I'm used to initializing an object, bailing if it's nil (which indicates a construction failure), or continuing with my function otherwise. I guess I'm inappropriately trying to apply that idiom here.

Comment: @bdesham: An object cannot magically be "nil". That makes no sense (in C++, but I believe it just doesn't make sense, period). An object has to have one of the values that its type permits. If you're shopping for cars, you'd expect a Ford, a Toyota and a Mercedes, but not nil. If you suddenly find yourself unable to create a value of the desired type (e.g. because you ran out of wheels), you simply don't *have* a car; it's *not* the case that you have a car but it's some kind of "special car value".

Comment: @KerrekSB I agree. Objective-C's type system is not expressive enough to represent that; instead, all objects are pointers, and nil pointers represent uninitialized objects or the like.

Comment: @bdesham: Well, Obj-C has a *different* type system and object model, e.g. variables in Obj-C are never objects, and the "declared type" of a variable isn't the domain from which the variable takes values, unlike in C++. That's why it's a really bad idea to transliterate code between languages rather than re-expressing the ideas *in* the new language.

Comment: @bdesham: I only said he should *consider* it. If his current design somehow needs the object later on yet allows for a situation in which the object may never be created due to some error situation, then the elimination of that error situation would be a good thing. This has nothing to do with RAII.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be doing everything you need to do *inside* the `try` block:

```
try {
    MyClass instance(3, 4, 5);

    // Use instance here
}
catch (MyClassException& ex) {
    cerr << "There was an error creating the MyClass." << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

After all, it is only within the `try` block that `instance` has been successfully created and so can be used.

I do wonder whether your `catch` block is really handling the exception. If you can't do anything to resolve the situation, you should be letting it propagate.

Comment: What if the code that uses `instance` could also throw an exception? Would I just add additional `catch` blocks for those? My instinct was to put as little code as possible in the `try`.

Comment: But if using instance can also throw many exceptions, is it good style to have one try-catch for all exceptions from different parts of code? It will looks better if there will be try-catch for each group of exceptions from each group of code, isn't it?

Comment: This is for a simple command-line app. If creation of the object fails, my options are to show the user some libc++ error about an unhandled exception or to show them my more informative error message. I don't think just letting the error propagate is really appropriate in this case.

Comment: @bdesham Regardless, if you have a `try` block, it needs to contain everything that depends on the exception not being thrown. That might even mean that it contains the entire content of the function (in which case you *could* use a [function try block](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5612486/150634)).

Comment: @JosephMansfield, Could, but then your code would fail a review when people don't know what it is :p

Comment: @bdesham: For the code that uses `instance`, you have two options. If they throw, can other code continue to use `instance`, or other objects created in the try block? If so, then you nest another try/catch block within this try block (or better, factor it out into a function with the try/catch block in there). If you *can't* do anything with `instance` after those other operations throw, then either add more catchers to the outer try block, or let the exception fall through.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Yes, this code is in main, so returning from within the `catch` block exits the application.

Comment: It makes the most sense for me to factor out the code dealing with `instance` into a separate function and then to call that function from within the `try`.

Comment: This doesn't scale well; what if the code needs 4 such objects? It'd be an unreadable mess.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamically allocate the instance using `new`:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> instance;
try
{
    instance.reset(new MyClass(3, 4, 5));
}
catch (const MyClassException& ex)
{
    std::cerr << "There was an error creating the MyClass." << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
// use instance as needed...
```

Comment: Note that you could write `MyClass& inst = *instance;` after the `catch`, in order to not need a dereference operator for future accesses of the object

Comment: Using `optional` as in my answer saves the heap allocation here, although that's not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a generic helper function that catches exceptions and the future `std::optional` (or `boost::optional`) to signal the successful or failed creation of the instance:

```
template< typename T, typename... Args >
std::optional< T > try_make( Args&&... args )
{
    try {
        return T{ std::forward< Args >( args )... };
    }
    catch( ... ) {
        return {};
    }
}
```

Using basically this:

```
auto instance = try_make< MyClass >(3, 4, 5);
```

Where `instance` is now an `optional<MyClass>`. To test the result and separate availablity of the instance from the error case is also simple:

```
if( auto instance = try_make< MyClass >( 3, 4, 5 ) ) {
    // use *instance, but this code is *not* in the try/catch block!
}
else {
    // creating the instance failed
}
```

Of course the exception information will be lost this way, but you could go for a less generic function and add some logging in the catch-block depending on your needs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can't judge the validity of OPs use-case. *If* it is valid, the answer might help. Others already pointed out that OP should check if this is really needed in the first place.

Comment: The last code block is a bit confusing; the OP's goal was that `instance` be in scope for the remainder of the function, but in that code it is scoped to the if...else block. Recommend just not having that last bit.

Comment: @M.M I don't think that was the goal. The goal was to work with the instance but *outside* of the try/catch block, so you don't accidentally catch exceptions from that code, only from the ctor. This can be achieved with my solution (as the comment in the code suggests).

Answer (score 1):

A variant of Remy's answer, but saving a dynamic allocation using `std::optional`:

```
std::optional<MyClass> instance_opt;
try {
    // could use `instance = MyClass(3, 4, 5)`, but that requires you to write a move constructor
    instance_opt.emplace(3, 4, 5);
}
catch (const MyClassException& ex) {
    std::cerr << "There was an error creating the MyClass." << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
MyClass& instance = *instance_opt;
// use instance as needed...
```