# Try catch scoping of class variable initialisation

Tags: c++, windows, exception, undefined-behavior, scoping

I'm having difficulties trying to find a solution that will allow me to keep the scope of an object local to a main method while catching a potential initialisation exception.

The pseudocode below tries to best illustrate my problem.

```
int main () {
    // Initialisation
    SomeObject * object;

    try {
         SomeObject obj; // Initialisation can cause an exception
         object = &obj;
    }
    catch (SomeException &ex) {
         // Handle exception
    }

    // object out of scope undefined behaviour

    // Application Logic
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that the object will be deleted once the try block ends and so the pointer when used will lead to undefined behaviour.

How can I do something like this and pass the object to the function scope so the object is not deleted?

I can use a c++14 solution in my project.

Comment: `to keep the scope of an object local to a main method` - why in this case and not declare it in scope where you want use it ? if you declare object as local variable in sub-function - it any way will be trash after you exit from this sub-function to `main`. so if you need have object in `main` scope - declare it here

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575896/catching-exceptions-from-a-constructor-means-that-my-instance-is-out-of-scope-af

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I do something like this and pass the object to the function scope so the object is not deleted?

You can use a smart pointer instead:

```
int main () {
    // Initialisation
    std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> object;

    try {
         object = std::make_unique<SomeObject>(); // Initialisation can cause an exception
    }
    catch (SomeException &ex) {
         // Handle exception
    }

    if(object) {
        // Application Logic
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way would be the "function try block"

```
int main() try
{
     SomeObject object;

     // Application logic - able to use object

     return 0;
}
catch (SomeException &ex)
{
     // Handle exception
}
```

This allows the exception handler to clean up before program termination.

If you want the exception handler within `main()`, then one option is

```
 int main()
 {
      try
      {
           SomeObject object;

            // Application logic able to use object
      }     
      catch (SomeException &ex)
      {
           // Handle exception
      }
}
```

With appropriate control structures (e.g. the entire `try`/`catch` within a loop) it is possible for the `catch` block to recover from the error, and recommence.

If you really want the definition of the object and the initialisation to be separate, you can do something like (C++11 and later);

```
#include <memory>
int main ()
{
    std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> object;

     try
     {
          object = std::make_unique<SomeObject>();
     }
     catch (SomeException &ex)
     {
         // Handle exception
     }

     // code here cannot assume construction of object succeeded

     if (object)
     {
         // Application Logic can assume object is properly constructed
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Before C++11, the above can use `std::auto_ptr` (which was deprecated in C++11 in favour of `unique_ptr`.

The suitable choice depends on whether you want the "Application logic" to be able to *assume* `object` has been properly constructed (i.e. the application logic is never executed until object construction succeeds) or if it must test for the possibility of failure.