# Recommended way to initialize a const variable with an expression which might throw

Tags: c++, exception, constants

You probably know situations like this where you just want to assign to a (`const`) variable with an expression which might fail (throw) (e.g.`container.at()`) which forces you to write boiler plate code:

```
void foo(const string &key) {
    auto it = data_store.find(key);
    if (it == data_store.end()) {
        return;
    }
    const auto & element = it->second;
    ...
    go on with `element`...
    ...
}
```

In Python you could write code like this:

```
def foo(name):
    try:
        element = data_store[key]
    except KeyError:
        return
    ..
    go on with `element`
    ..
```

.. with is less noisy because you don't introduce that useless extra `it` just for checking existence.

If C++'s `try` would not introduce a variable scope you could just use `at()`:

```
void foo(const string &key) {
    try {
        const auto & element = data_store.at(key);
    } catch (const out_of_range &) {
        return;
    }
    ...
    go on with `element`...
    ...
}
```

What's the way to go here if you don't want to abandon *constness* and keep your code clean?

If lambdas only could have a `try`/`catch` body you could write

```
void foo(const string &key) {
    const auto & element = [&] () -> T try {
        return data_store.at(key);
    } catch () {
        return;
    } ();
    ...
    go on with `element`...
    ...
}
```

Some answers to similar questions suggest `try`/`catch` blocks around all the code:

```
void foo(const string &key) {
    try {
        const auto & element = data_store.at(key);
        ...
        go on with `element`...
        ...
    } catch (const out_of_range &) {
        return;
    } catch (some other exception) {
        ...
    } catch (some other exception) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But I don't like this because of three reasons:

- there's no visual correlation between `at()` and it's `catch` block
- there might be code that also need you to handle `out_of_range`
- you have to write nested code

Which (nice, short and clean) alternatives do you know?

Comment: Do you really *need* to check for existence? If `data_store` is a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`, then the act of just accessing an "element" (as in `data_store[key]`) will *create* that element. What is the use-case? What is the actual problem you try to solve?

Comment: In addition to the comment above: Do you really have to catch the exception that might be thrown at this point? What exactly is your exception handler going to do?

Comment: Exception handling allows *presumptive* code. I.e., you run some statement of code. You've now arrived at the next statement. Because you're *not* now within some catch-block you can *presume* the statement just executed did *not* throw, and therefore, worked. In short, your last example is easily most common (at least where I work). Writing procedural wrappers to catch exceptions for logging and either re-throwing or consuming are usually the deviance to that. Your description seems to be saying in summary: "I want inline try-catch safety without inline try-catch safety. Tall order.

Comment: My question is about assigning a variable in a `try` block - the `at()` example is just for having some actual code. You could also imagine opening a file or anything like this. Anyway sometimes you *might* want to auto-insert into a `map` but this is not always the case (and a *very* bad idea to let `map` behave like this in my eyes)

Comment: What is the problem with your first version (the one with the `find`)? Why is it boilerplate code? In my eyes, that's the best version. Fastest, cleanest (And even, if you don't break that `if` into 3 lines, then it is the shortest one). Why complicate things with exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three good options on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575896/catching-exceptions-from-a-constructor-means-that-my-instance-is-out-of-scope-af), there's not really any other option.

Those cases assume we are initializing an object; for initializing a reference as you are, apply the techniques to `std::reference_wrapper`, or a pointer.

---

BTW I would not discount your first code sample so quickly. It's simpler than all the other options, and it is a common recommendation in C++ to only use exceptions for exceptional conditions -- things you do not expect to be a normal part of the function's contract.  It's not idiomatic to use them as a shortcut.

In other words, if the function design is to do nothing if the lookup fails, then throw-catching is an unnecessary complication to the function. You've just written an even uglier version of C-style error handling.

The whole point of the `at()` accessor is that your function can be kept simple by **not** catching -- the exception can be left to propagate up to a more general error handler.