# Why does this C++ function definition not require curly braces?

Tags: c++, function, syntax

I was reading Stroustrup's "Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++" and found that he included a function without the main curly braces without explaining himself and online people say it is impossible.

I have compiled the code and it works totally fine.

```
void f()
    try {} 
    catch(...) {}
```

I expect to get a compiler error from this but I do not and it works fine. I am using C++17.

Comment: C tag removed, obviously this is not C.

Answer (score 7):

> not require curly braces?

There are curly braces:

```
void f() try {} catch(...) {}
             ^^
```

This is a [Function-try-block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block):

> A function-try-block associates a sequence of catch clauses with the entire function body

Comment: Is there any functional difference with `{ try {} catch(...) {} }`? Ive never seen this before and I'm a bit puzzled as to why its allowed. Only seems to add confusion.

Comment: @Borgleader there is when used for constructors and you want to catch errors from init-lists, for example. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612486/when-is-a-function-try-block-useful . No difference for regular functions.

Comment: @Borgleader I've used them just to reduce indent on methods that need to catch almost all exceptions. Quite useful when working with CPP/WinRT for example